# Add text inside Azure AD B2C signup user flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to display a simple sentence with a link: "By signing up you agree to the terms".

I am using the Azure AD B2c User Flows. I don't need or want a checkbox, just the ability to notify the user of the terms and data protection (GDPR).

I understand that I can create a custom page layout, but then the terms would need to be outside the signup box and they should be just above the sign up button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `textbox`, then use CSS to restyle it.
In Custom policy you can use the `paragraph` claim type.

Comment: I attempted this. Using absolute positioning I can place a div with some text and links above the signup button. It gets more complicated since I am using the unified flow which means the text also needed to fit above the social login buttons with the same css, but I managed it by adjusting margins and positioning of the elements. Mobile adds more complexity and it also needs to fit on the verify email page with the same css which became impossible. I wanted to avoid custom policies as I want to keep login solution simple, but for legal reasons need to display the terms.